# Unity, WaitUntil in a self-made message box class

Tags: unity, coroutines, monobehaviour

I managed to make a simple message box prefab with a `Text` and a `Button` through `Canvas`, and then instantiate it through the constructor.

```
public class MessageBox
{
    public MessageBox(string msg)
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load(@"MsgBox"));

        obj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = msg;
    }
}
```

So when another script needed it, simply do

```
MessageBox mb = new MessageBox("This is a test message!");
```

This all worked fine, but then I wish to change it to like normal MessageBox where the code was suspended, but not locked, until the user click the OK or Cancel button.

I managed to do it by calling a coroutine **`in the calling script`**.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("Do");
}

IEnumerator Do()
{
    MessageBox mb = new MessageBox("This is also a test message!");

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => GlobalVariables.MsgBoxClicked == true);
    //GlobalVariables is a separate class containing some static variables.
    Debug.Log("Done!");
}
```

(You have to set the `MsgBoxClicked` to `false` when the prefab is created and set it to `true` when the button is clicked, of course.)

But that means every time I needed to use the message box, I need to call a coroutine!

And that's super inefficient no matter how you looked at it!

So I tried to move the coroutine into the `MessageBox` class itself.

But now here comes the problem!

The `MessageBox` does NOT inherit from `MonoBehaviour`!

And you can't call a coroutine without it!

I had tried to make the `MessageBox` inherited from `MonoBehaviour`, but the Unity warned me **`This is not allowed`** every time I tried to new it! Even though the game ran smoothly.

I even tried to new the `MonoBehaviour` itself and call its `StartCouroutine`, but of course, the same warning popped up! And this time the game won't even run!

I also tried to use the old `AutoResetEvent`, but it locked the whole thing and crashed my game!

So, could somebody be so kind and teach me how to get around it!?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity doesn’t really support modal dialogs in the way you want, but there are some workaround, like setting the time scale to zero while it’s displayed, and adding a click-blocking later between the message box and everything underneath it.

There are also better ways to wait for the message box to be dismissed than a coroutine, such as a UnityEvent.

That said, if you just want to move your coroutine into the MessageBox class, it should be pretty simple: (warning: untested)

```
public class MessageBox : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private System.Action onDismiss;
    public static void ShowMessage(string msg, System.Action onDismiss)
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("MsgBox"));

        obj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = msg;
        MessageBox msg = obj.AddComponent<MessageBox>(); //or this component could be added to the prefab in the inspector.
        msg.onDismiss = onDismiss;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Do");
    }

    IEnumerator Do()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => GlobalVariables.MsgBoxClicked);
        //GlobalVariables is a separate class containing some static variables.
        if (onDismiss != null)
            onDismiss();
    }
}
```

And then the code that wants to show the message can simply use

```
MessageBox.ShowMessage("This is a test message!", () => {
    Debug.Log("Done!");
});
```

Basically, MonoBehaviour objects can’t exist on their own. They are components that must be attached to a GameObject, which is what the call to AddComponent is doing.

Comment: `msg.onComplete = onDismiss;` won't work! There is NO `onComplete`! Could you please be so kind and fix it!? Much appreciated!

Comment: Whoops. I accidentally used onDismiss in one place and onComplete in another. Try onDismiss in all places.